# How to keep the music player consistent in wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I want to keep a music player at the bottom of page and want uninterrupted playback of music while hoping from page to page.

Currently I have this design

```
    <iframe src="wpfrontpage.php"></iframe>
    <?php  include 'player.php';?>
```

wpfrontpage.php is where the wp_head, page content and wp_foot are called

I want to know what's wrong if i kept it like this? I mean any thing against standards?
And what's the right solution?

I also want to load the player when the main page has completed loading.

Regrds,

Comment: Go either with a pop up or the iframe. There is nothing standard or no  t standard in doing this , but it could be an issue for search engine to display all the website in an iframe. But it is the only way not to stop the player when you change pages.

Comment: Thats what I found easier. I had thought of AJAX but won't it be heavy to load lot of html via ajax?

Comment: the problem with ajax is that will need to wire all the links in your page to ajax calls and what about the javascript managed by wordpress ? etc ... and it wont solve the SEO problems either...

Comment: Hey! I have found something similar, this guy is loading it's pages via ajax and using wp as well http://www.ericpaulsnowden.com/blog

and here's the like a guy has asked something similar.
Can u plz help me clarify. I mean when i inspected XHR, of the site, it loads the complete page on every link click.

will it not become so heavy??
Or let it be?

here is the wp so question link

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25186/how-to-load-whole-wordpress-pages-dynamically-with-ajax-jquery-like-this-followi?answertab=active#tab-top

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax calls to load the content.

Comment: Hi, 
I just got my site AJAXified using this tutorial. Its working as intended except I have to make changes to load styles and scripts for the pages being called

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html
Inspired from this screen cast http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/81-ajaxing-a-wordpress-theme/

So, I am on to it. Looks like I have to do lot of changes.